# Is it possible to have a non-full-screen Java application that covers the Windows taskbar?

Tags: java, java-8, jframe

I am trying to create a application where it uses two JFrame taking half the screen each. But what I wish to achieve was to have a 'full screen' effect with two separate frames.

I have tried various way like using the JFrame api's *toFront* method and etc but still not workable.

When user interact with my application, they can open up forms which must always be on top even when the jframe is clicked. Currently if I were to set *alwaysOnTop* to true, when I clicked on jframe, the form will be push back behind the frame.

This set of codes **(TestApp2)** shows the full screen effect I want to achieve which is to cover the Windows task bar.

```
package doubleframe;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TestApp2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestApp2();
}

public TestApp2() {
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int height = screenSize.height;
    int width = (screenSize.width);

    JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
    frame1.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
    frame1.setUndecorated(true);
    frame1.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

This set of codes **(TestApp)** shows how my application is like, but not able to achieve the affect of covering the taskbar.

```
package doubleframe;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestApp {

private int size = 2;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestApp();
}

public TestApp() {
    initFrames();
}


private void initFrames() {
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int height = screenSize.height;
    int width = (screenSize.width / size);

    JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
    frame1.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
    frame1.setUndecorated(true);
    frame1.setVisible(true);

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    panel1.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);

    frame1.getContentPane().add(panel1);

    //frame 2
    JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
    frame2.setBounds(width, 0, width, height);
    frame2.setUndecorated(true);
    frame2.setVisible(true);

    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    panel2.setBounds(width, 0, width, height);

    frame2.getContentPane().add(panel2);
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `setAlwaysOnTop(true)`?

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak 
Yes i did, unfortunately it did not fit my case.
i have forgotten to mention that my application will have popup forms (eg, jpanel), which when shown suppose to remain on top even when i click on the jframes.

Comment: @jus you can make the popup always on top as well, which would hopefully bring it in front of other windows. By the way, why to have two frames at all? Why you cannot have a single frame with two panels in it?

Answer (score 0):

You can set both frames to be always on top:

```
frame1.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
frame2.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

If you still want to be able to alt-tab to windows underneath these two, you can add a `WindowFocusListener` to each frame, which on focus loss would check whether any of the two frames is focused, and if not, `setAlwaysOnTop(false)`. Similarly you would have to enable it back on focus gain. This is however a bit hacky and not that straightforward to implement, due to the order in which these events are fired. The idea below, but you might have to improve it:

```
WindowFocusListener listener = new WindowAdapter() {
    AtomicBoolean switchingOff = new AtomicBoolean();

    @Override
    public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
        if (!switchingOff.get() && !frame1.isAlwaysOnTop() && !frame2.isAlwaysOnTop()) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                frame1.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                frame2.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void windowLostFocus(WindowEvent e) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            if (!frame1.isFocused() && !frame2.isFocused()) {
                switchingOff.set(true);
                frame1.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
                frame2.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> switchingOff.set(false));
            }
        });
    }
};
frame1.addWindowFocusListener(listener);
frame2.addWindowFocusListener(listener);
```

Comment: unfortunately this solution does not fit my case, explanation is in the the above comment section